# Keras: solving new problems I do not know the answer

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I try to summarize my problem as good as I can, but it is really don't easy for me because I do not really know which key words to ask about...

I am quite new in machine learning and used Keras to solve problems I know the answer.

Example:
As an input have tons of photos of different object like cars, birds... (x-value) and a label what they are (y-value). The program can then recognize objects on new photos. The usual stuff.

How can I write a program that discovers new ways to solve a problem?

Example:
Players play a game, and I record their moves as well as the result/score. How can I write program that finds the optimal strategy? I tried to just sort out games with bad scores but I guess there is a better way, something like

if score is really good, then learn this strongly
if score is slightly over average, then learn this
if score is slightly under average, then  do not learn this
if score is really bad,then avoid this strongly

Can you give me a hint? Would be really nice.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are talking about `reinforcement learning`, your example about players play a game and return score is what exactly `reinforcement learning` is. Reinforcement learning works using punish and reward concept, the model will try to do something and when the model returns a good result, the model will get a reward, and otherwise, when the model returns a bad result, it will be punished. Perhaps you can do some research and google about it.

But in my opinion since you mentioned that you are quite new to machine learning and keras, you probably need to learn about `supervised learning` first. Your case about photo (x) and label (y) is all about supervised learning is.